# How to write the view of saving a model which having foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new in Django developing and I have a model Customers that is in a relationship with a ZipCode model. So from the model Customers, I want to get the zipCode in the ZipCode model. This, the ZipCode model has 4 attributes such as pk which is an aut_increment, zipCode which is unique, city and state. Therefore, my issues are: How to get the zipCode attribute as a foreign key in the Customer model and how the view of saving the customer object can be written? Below is are the Customers and the ZipCode models:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    customerID = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    zipCode = models.ForeignKey(ZipCode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField()

class ZipCode(models.Model):
    zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.zipCode + ' ' + self.city + ' ' + self.state
```

Here also the view add_customers which is not working:

```
def add_Custmers(request):
    # try:
    #     zipCode=ZipCode.objects.get(slug=zipcode_slug)
    # except ZipCode.DoesNotExist:
    #     zipCode=None
    form=CustomersForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'customers.html', context
```

[image: add customer form]

I attached the add customer form for more details

```
class CustomersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    customerID = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    firstName = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastName = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    phoneNumber = forms.CharField(max_length=14)
    zipCode = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ZipCode.objects.all())
    address = forms.Textarea()
    class Meta:
        model=Customers
        fields=('customerID','firstName','lastName','phoneNumber', 'zipCode', 'address',)
```

Above is the form I define

Comment: How are you defining the form? If it's `forms.ModelForm`, it should create `ModelChoiceField` out of the box, and the related zip-code should be saved properly; unless the issue is different?

Comment: Why is your view not working? What happens - do you see a specific error?

Comment: @Will Keeling The error I'm getting after applying the solution suggested is: "object has no attribute 'zipCode' "

Comment: @MohamedAbdillah the suggested solution won't work, because `zipCode` is a HTTP request parameter, not an attribute of the `request` object itself. You'll need to retrieve the parameter with `request.GET['zipCode']`

Comment: Thank you so much @Will Keeling. The  second one is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saving the Form right after checking if it's valid or not, do this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    customer = form.save(commit=False)
    customer.zipCode = request.zipCode 
    form.save()
```

Let me know if it's still not working.

EDIT : Sorry didn't check it earlier. It should be `request.POST['zipCode']` instead of `request.zipCode`

Comment: It is displaying this error: object has no attribute 'zipCode'

Comment: @ mfrackowiak, please have a look on the form I created.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with form that you created the zip code should be saved properly, if you however want to access it somehow before saving - after calling `form.is_valid()` it should be accessible under: `form.instance.zipCode` or `form.cleaned_data["zipCode"]`

Comment: @Sulove Bista, any progress, please?

Comment: @Sulove Bista, after adding this line of code form.cleaned_data["zipCode"] and remove this line of code customer.zipCode = request.zipCode from my code, it is saving but instead of the zipCode it is saving the whole row of the ZipCode model

Comment: Hey @MohamedAbdillah . Try this instead of request.zipCode , request.POST['zipCode'] . It should work then.